# EmailAddress is required for Hold For Pickup

Tags: usps, stamps.com

I am getting when calling CreateIndicium method of SwsimV62SoapClient service.

Error: EmailAddress is required for Hold For Pickup.

Can you please suggest.

Comment: Need more "blood, sweat, and tears" than what you have provided.  Need a Schema, Current Code, and Ideal effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my prediction you have used soapclient's  GetRates method.

e.g.

```
Authenticator = soapclient.GetRates(Authenticator, Rate, out Rates);
Rate = Rates[0];
```

But after calling your function you have to remove values from Rate.AddOns object.

e.g.

```
Rate.AddOns = null;
```

A  object previously returned from the GetRates web method. Remove  elements not desired for the indicium.